# How can I redefine \part command when use package title sec is being used in preamble

Tags: sectioning, parts

I need to change the format of the \part command. Right now I'm using:
I have a report class document using `\usepackage{title sec}`

```
\titleformat{\part}{\centering\normalsize}{\thepart.}{1em}{}{}
```

I need to change the formatting from I. NAME OF MY PART to PART I. NAME OF MY PART in the document body.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to do this:

```
\titleformat{\part}{\centering\normalsize}{PART \thepart.}{1em}{}{}
```